# Angularjs regex routes for url

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to create a route `/:url` to match `http://localhost/#/http://www.google.com`

and I want to get url param in controller by

```
var url = $stateParams.url; // url = http://www.google.com
```

Is there any way to achieve that scene? Please suggest, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite difficult to pass encoded slashes in urls as the browser will change it to a slash. The only solution I came up with is to double encode the slashes. I used [this encoder](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) to do the encoding but it could be done in your angular app if needed using `encodeURIComponent`. That means the url is instead `#/http%3A%252F%252Fwww.google.com`.

To setup the parameter you first have to add it to the routing config in `app.js`. I've added the parameter called `url` and made it optional with the `?` symbol:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/:url?', {
        templateUrl: 'view.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
});
```

Then in your controller you can use `$routeParams` to get the url. But since the slashes are double encoded you need to use `decodeURIComponent` to decode the url:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams) {
  $scope.url = decodeURIComponent($routeParams.url);
})
```

Click the `a` link in the demo for the google url.

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/5oeO1GWnu936F92XkI7m?p=preview)